# How to create a complex if then statement using specific text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm not sure where to start with this. I want to create a column in Excel that will essentially simplify another column. I have a column of dates with month, day, year, and a time. I want to use a formula to search for the year and then output that year into a new column. I am using Excel 2013 for this.

Something like IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%2011%,A1)), "2011", "??").

Except I'd like the formula to be able to incorporate outputting 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, or 2016 if that year is found instead.

Where do I start on this? is it even possible?

Thank you

Comment: is that column formatted as date? if yes, then you can simply use `YEAR()`, if not, do you have a fixed format? please post some sample data to help us understanding your issue.

Comment: The data wasn't in a date format but its easily converted into one. An example is: "06/25/11 12:00 AM."
Edit: I didn't know of the year function..that worked perfect. Thank you! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is stored as date (number) then you can use [`YEAR()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9).

If it's stored as text, then [`DATEVALUE()` function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252) may help.